All my chats got revealed in my previous phone when someone else tried to login their whatsapp
I used to use whatsapp on my previous phone which i do not anymore. That phone doesnt have my sim nor any of my google accounts in it anymore. Recently a family member put their sim card in this phone and began to use whatsapp but when they did, all my old chats on that device came up right away. WHYYY ISS THATT? THIS IS horrible. I do not wish for them to see my private conversations. Why is this happening when i am technically not connected to that device???
I tried looking at whatsapp blogs but it doesnt specify why this scary thing has happened. Please help

Uninstall whatsapp and remove all the cache then all your messages should be removed from the old phone
